# Trying to add max key to dictionary in another dictionary Error

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to add the max key of the first dictionary in a second but when I run it shows me a syntax error for `sack{}`. And I can't seem to figure out why this error occurs. Could anyone explain what the error is? Thank you.

The Code is as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys

def vault(dataFile):
    gem = []
    weight = []
    value = []
    valPerCarat = []    
    for l in dataFile.readlines():      
        attribute = l.split(",")
        gem.append(str(attribute[0]))
        weight.append(float(attribute[1]))
        value.append(int(attribute[2]))
        valPerCarat.append(int(attribute[2])/float(attribute[1]))
    booty = theft_preparation(gem, valPerCarat)
    return (booty)  

    #return(gem, weight, value, valPerCarat)

def theft_preparation(gem, valPerCarat):
    loot = dict(zip(gem, valPerCarat)
    sack = {}
    precious = 0
    while (precious =< 5.00):
        max (loot, key=loot.get)
        precious = dict.get(key, default=None)
        precious +=precious
        sack.update(key)        
        del(key)

    return (sack)


def main():
    fileFound = False
    while not fileFound:
        fileName = input("File name containing jewel data: ")
        try:
            dataFile = open(fileName, "r")
            fileFound = True

        except:
            print("Could not find that file -- try again")
    knapsackCapacity = 5.00 
    print (vault(dataFile))


main()
```

Comment: you have mistakes and lots of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on the previous line:

```
loot = dict(zip(gem, valPerCarat)
                                 ^ HERE
```

Comment: ...and that's just the first of several errors (`=<`, incorrect usage of `max()`, `dict.get()` and `.update()`, lots more of strange stuff (`del(key)`, `precious += precious`) - this will take some work...

Comment: Yeah I have not learned this stuff in school it's just stuff I have seen in the internet. Thanks though